# GPU L1 Cache Coherence

Tags: gpu, gpgpu

In OPENCL and CUDA, there are primitives, i.e. barrier() and syncthread() respectively,  to enforce coherence for the L1 data cache/shared memory. Does this imply that the cache itself is not coherent, i.e. no CPU like cache coherence protocol implemented in the hardware for L1 cache ?

Answer (score 6):

Most of the cache coherency algorithm are not scalable for GPUs. In addition, having cache coherency in GPUs introduces significant traffic to the GPU memory system which is already a bottleneck for GPU. Therefore, they use a simple eviction technique to keep the data consistent between private and shared caches. Simply to say, whenever there is a write to global data, the cache line having that data is evicted to shared cache.
Recently, some techniques are introduced but I doubt that they are actually being implemented in the hardware.

Comment: so, do you mean whenever there is a global memory store, the data will be evicted from L1 cache to L2 cache (typically L2 is shared by SPs)? Or will the data be evicted from all the cache all the way down to global memory?

Answer (score 0):

in nvidia roadmap, since fermi arch introduced the l1 and shared l2 data cache, the write-back strategy might be write-evit in L1 data cache as AmirC mentioned, there would be occured cache non-conherency. kepler arch introduce a new read-only data cache for load gloabl data, but they can not allowed global data writed in l1 after kepler arch (maxwell,pascal,volta,turing,ampere etc.)